# Inkscape alternatives for Qt Svg Dom Manipulation

Tags: xml, qt, svg, inkscape

I Want to save and load and edit SVG scene in Qt and also need to manipulate graphic item's attributes like DOM manipulation

Everywhere I search I will encounter Inkscape as an expert SVG editor but its in GTK and not Qt

I want to know if there is a way to embed Inkscape in an actual Qt application or using it's API or maybe any Inkscape alternative is there that can set Item's Ids for example and setting their attributes? 
is there any third-party for this or I have to implement it myself?

right now I'm just using QtSvg library but it's very naive and QSvgRenderer and QSvgGenerator are not good classes to master svg this way.

Comment: Would any XML library do?

Comment: if I use XML library I have to implement SVG's attributes myself, as I mentioned I want to avoid this by using some kind of C++/Qt library to parse xml file.